# Matlab: meaning of eps

Tags: matlab

Suppose I have following code:

```
 T  =  0.1;
 t  =   − 0.5: 0.001: 0.5;
 x  =   pi*t/T; 
 y  =   sin (x  +   eps )/(x  +   eps );
 plot  (t, y);
```

My question is: What is purpose of `eps`?

I have got following graph:

[image]

Even without `eps`, I get the same picture. Does `eps` have the same meaning as a limit definition, when `h` approaches `0`? Does it measure the actual approximation of the `sin` function?

Comment: Just to avoid dividing by zero.

Comment: wouldn't it be better to make a special case for x == 0 instead of deliberately adding error to every value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest you read the following:

http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/eps.html

In your case, `eps` prevents from dividing by zero. However, I don't think it is necessary in the numerator (also note the `./` instead of `/`):

```
y  =   sin (x )./(x  +   eps );
```

Comment: In fact it seems to cope without the `eps` in the denominator as well. Yo do need the `./` though.

Comment: @am304 `eps` is a safety guard.  If you examine the result of `sin(x) ./x`, you'll probably find an `Inf` (or possibly a `NaN`) when `x==0`.  IIRC, `plot` removes these when you plot them.  The `eps` is still quite useful if you're doing something other than plotting data.

Answer (score 4):

eps is the minimum distance Matlab can recognize between two numbers x and y.
for example

```
>> format long e
>> x=1;y=x+eps;
>> y-x

ans =

2.220446049250313e-016

>> x=1;y=x+eps/2;
>> y-x

ans =
0
```

we observe that y-x=0 and Matlab cannot recognise difference less than eps:

```
>> eps
ans =
2.220446049250313e-016
```

**reference:** http://www.researchgate.net/post/What_does_eps_in_MATLAB_mean_What_is_the_value_of_it

Comment: -1. That's not true. Consider: `x = eps; y = eps / 4; diff = x - y; assert(0 < diff && diff < eps)`. The value `eps` is the minimum distance Matlab (well, IEEE floating point) can recognize between the constant `1` and any other number `x`.

Answer (score 1):

There is no double number between `1` and `(1+eps)` due to limilting resolution in `MATLAB`. ie. `eps` is the smallest number that can be represented in `MATLAB`. In your problem it avoids division by zero even if `x` is zero.

Comment: `eps` is not the smallest number that can be represented in Matlab, that smallest number is `realmin`.  `eps`, without further elaboration, is the difference between `1.0` (as a 64-bit IEEE floating-point number) and the next largest 64-bit IEEE floating-point number. Evaluation of `eps` returns `2.2204e-16`, evaluation of `realmin` returns `2.2251e-308`.

Comment: @High Performance Mark: No, the smallest double precision floating point number is `eps(realmin)` = `eps*realmin` = `2^-1074` = `4.940656458412465e-324`. `realmin` is the smallest "[normalized](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_number_(computing))" double precision floating point number. The numbers smaller than `realmin` are called "[subnormal" or "denormal" numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_number_(computing)) and are there to guarantee the precision of the normal numbers is retained in calculations, i.e., never underflows.